# Get the last non null value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: My data]

Is it possible to use the last value (Balance) that isn't null?

In my data there is no value for 2018-07-31, so it should use the value from 2018-06-30 which is 0.

There can be several rows in a row that is null. So it should not always take the row above.

Okay, i will try with the formatting here on SO, but im new so it will probably take some tries to get right:

This is my data:

```
AccountNo EOM Company Balance    
7040    2020-01-31  NF  NULL    
7040    2020-02-29  NF  NULL    
7040    2020-03-31  NF  NULL    
7040    2020-04-30  NF  NULL    
7040    2020-05-31  NF  NULL    
7050    2019-07-31  NF  0.00    
7050    2019-08-31  NF  NULL    
7050    2019-09-30  NF  NULL    
7050    2019-10-31  NF  NULL    
7050    2019-11-30  NF  NULL    
7050    2019-12-31  NF  56224.00    
7050    2020-01-31  NF  NULL    
7050    2020-02-29  NF  0.00
```

I want my result to be like below.
I want the previous NON NULL value if there is one on that account in that company. If there is no NON NULL values it should just be NULL.

```
AccountNo   EOM Company Balance
7040    2020-01-31  NF  NULL
7040    2020-02-29  NF  NULL
7040    2020-03-31  NF  NULL
7040    2020-04-30  NF  NULL
7040    2020-05-31  NF  NULL
7050    2019-07-31  NF  0.00
7050    2019-08-31  NF  0.00
7050    2019-09-30  NF  0.00
7050    2019-10-31  NF  0.00
7050    2019-11-30  NF  0.00
7050    2019-12-31  NF  56224.00
7050    2020-01-31  NF  56224.00
7050    2020-02-29  NF  0.00
```

Edit number 9000: Thanks for the help. I am still getting used to SO, so my formatting skills wasn't the best.

Comment: There is no viable attempt atm. I spend all day yesterday trying to figure it out. My expected output would be something like this:


AllEOM       | EOM  | AccountNo | Company | Balance | KontoType|
2018-06-30 | NULL | 5016          |  xx            | 0.0         | null

Comment: You can use `lag` analytical function  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Although a picture speaks a thousand words. We prefer data in text format. Please share your input records in text format by editing the original post.

Comment: And add your full expected results for the sample data to the question.

Comment: @DigvijayS: Thanks for telling me about `LAG`, that will be useful in the future. I don't see how it could be used here, though, since it requires a fixed offset, whereas the OP requires "go back until the first non-NULL value is found".

Comment: Which column is the basis for getting rows that is NOT NULL? The date or the balance? If it's is date column why not use SELECT MAX(AIIEOM) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE BALANCE IS NOT NULL

Comment: I just edited my post. It should be more understandable now.

Comment: You seem to want the last value before a `NULL` row.  But that is not clear.  Nor is it clear what to return if there are no `NULL` rows or multiple such rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.  You are looking to fill in `balance` with the last value that is not `null`.  SQL -- in general -- supports an option on `lag()` that does this.  But SQL Server does not (yet???) support this.  So, one method is a lateral join:

```
select t.*, t2.balance as imputed_balance
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.AccountNo = t.AccountNo and
            t2.Balance is not null and
            t2.EOM <= t.EOM
      order by t2.EOM desc
     ) t2;
```

You can also do this with window functions.  Define a "group" as the number of non-NULL values up to each value.  Then spread the non-null value over this group:

```
select t.*,
       max(balance) over (partition by accountNo, grp) as imputed_balance
from (select t.*,
             count(balance) over (partition by accountNo order by EOM) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

This will be faster than `apply` if there are lost of months per account.

Both of these can be incorporated into `update` statements, if you actually want to modify the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The last one worked with a few changes.

Comment: Just a note on SQL Server support for returning non-null values. SQL Server 2022 (as well as Azure SQL DB and Azure Managed Instances) now support ignoring nulls:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#-ignore-nulls--respect-nulls-

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to evaluate all rows with `NULL` as value and the corresponding last non-null date. Basing on this you can fetch the value of the corresponding date in a join to the same table. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  d datetime,
  v decimal(19,4)
)
GO

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES
('2020-02-01', 1.5)
,('2020-02-02', 4.2)
,('2020-02-03', 0.5)
,('2020-02-04', NULL)
,('2020-02-05', NULL)
,('2020-02-06', NULL)
,('2020-02-07', 10.5)
GO

WITH cte AS(
SELECT d
  FROM T1
  WHERE v IS NULL
),
cteLast AS(
SELECT c.d, max(t.d) AS dmax
  FROM cte c
  JOIN T1 t ON t.d < c.d AND t.v IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY c.d
)
SELECT t.d, t.v, ISNULL(t.v, t2.v) vNew
  FROM T1 t
  LEFT JOIN cteLast c ON c.d = t.d
  LEFT JOIN T1 t2 ON t2.d = c.dmax
```

Here a fiddle to demonstrate the idea:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb131/7/1

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery to calculate the max date with null Balance, and then return the last record before that date.

```
select top 1 *
from BalanceTable
where AllEOM < (select max(AllEOM) from BalanceTable where Balance is null) and
      Balance is not null
order by AllEOM desc
```

You haven't explained well what you want to return when you have more than one null. My first proposal was to return the previous record before the last null, but if you want to return the previous record for all the nulls, then query all the null records and join them with their previous record.

```
select distinct PreviousRecord.*
from BalanceTable as NullRecords
     outer apply (select top 1 BalanceTable.*
                  from BalanceTable
                  where BalanceTable.AllEOM < NullRecords.AllEOM and 
                        BalanceTable.Balance is not null
                  order by BalanceTable.AllEOM desc
                 ) as PreviousRecord
where NullRecords.Balance is null
```

Comment: I guess I understand your approach, but what will happen if you have a value row such as: 1, 2, 3, NULL, NULL, 6, NULL, 8. The expected output (as far as I understood the OP) would be 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 8

Comment: @Tyron78 I'm not really sure what the OP wants when there are several Nulls, that's why I have proposed different queries. Although you are right that I doesn't seem right for when there are two nulls consecutive. I have updated the answer to return only the previous not null on those cases. In your sequence the result would be 3, 6 (the values before the nulls). I think that this is what he wants, but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by AllEOM desc) as seq
      from table t
      where balance is not null
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```